# Qiniu : Always return "405 Not Allowed"

Tags: php, ios, afnetworking, audio-streaming

I am trying to integrate Qiniu SDK for audio uploading. As per it's documentation, we first need to get Access Token. 
Because we need to pass AccessToken in any api call.

http://developer.qiniu.com/docs/v6/api/reference/acc/access-token.html

I am trying to call API with following data.

```
host : http://acc.qbox.me
method : POST
Parameters : 
grant_type = password
username = <username>
password = <password>
```

But still it give me following response

```
<html>
<head><title>405 Not Allowed</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>405 Not Allowed</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.4</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Please any can guide me what is wrong into it.

Comment: 405 is METHOD not allowed. Are you sure your service supports POST?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the php sdk has provided the  accesstoken function.
the Auth class is here: https://github.com/qiniu/php-sdk/blob/master/src/Qiniu/Auth.php

in your project you should require this file. 
and there many examples here:https://github.com/qiniu/php-sdk/tree/master/examples

here is the upload token examples:

```
<?php
 require_once '/path/to/autoload.php';
 use Qiniu\Auth;
 $accessKey = 'Access_Key';
 $secretKey = 'Secret_Key';     
 $auth = new Auth($accessKey, $secretKey);
 $bucket = 'Bucket_Name';
 $upToken = $auth->uploadToken($bucket);
 echo $upToken;
```

hope it can help you.

Comment: I install xampp on my mac. After it, I put "php-sdk-master" in "htdocs" folder. I test "download_token.php" by change Accesskey & screteKey.

Comment: Now, I can generate Accesstoken.

Answer (score 1):

If you use iOS 9 SDK, all your calls should use https due to ATP (App transport security). If you do want to have exceptions and need to allow specific http calls, you should add exceptions to your .plist file:

```
key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
        <key>http://acc.qbox.me</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
            <false/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
            <string>TLSv1.2</string>
            <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

You can even allow all http traffic by adding this to your .plist file (but Apple does not recommend this):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

Comment: I also test on POSTMAN tool from google crome store.
It also give me same result

Comment: Try to call it with https instead of http. Passing username and password params over http is not a good idea and the serve may be blocking this by returning 405 errors.